# Proof of Leibniz series expansion for $\pi$

Tags: integration, inequality

> It can be shown that for positive integer values of $n$,
>   $$1+2(\cos x + \cos 2x + \cos 3x + \dots + \cos nx) = \frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin(x/2)},\quad\text{Do NOT prove this}$$
>   (i) Show that:
>   $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin(x/2)}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}+2(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\dots+\frac{1}{n}\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}))$$
>   (ii) Show that:
>   $$\left\lvert\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin(x/2)}\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert\leq\frac{1}{2n+1}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(x/2)}{\sin^2(x/2)}\mathrm{d}x\right)$$
>   (iii) Hence, show that as $n\to\infty$:
>   $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin(n+1/2)x}{\sin(x/2)}\mathrm{d}x \to \pi$$

Does anyone have a website or a link to the solution for the Leibniz Series expansion for $\pi$ that has all this trigonometry things in it? (Simple solution as I am in Year 12) Most of the online solutions for Leibniz Series use geometric series or something like that.

Anyone part i was very simple, as you just use the expansion in the question and then you can easily integrate to get the required result.

However, not sure what to do for part ii. I tried integration right hand side as $\cot(x/2)\csc(x/2)$ which gives $-2\csc(x/2)$ but I'm not sure if that approach is correct and how I am able to prove the inequality part. Also because the limits have switched so I am slightly confused.

Comment: How confident are you in the manipulation of Fourier series and with the properties of Fejér kernel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) ? (i) is a straightforward consequence of the premise about $\sum\cos(kx)$, by the way.